# Read text file reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to read a text file (.txt) content on file browser using react technology.

Is any specific npm available to that?

Please give me a sample code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FileReader`

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = ()=>{
    console.log(reader.result)
  }
reader.readAsDataURL(filename)
```

And `filename` should obtained from a Html input and it will pass by `onchange` event as `e.target.files[0]`

```
<input type="file" onchange = {(e)=>setFilename(e.target.files[0])} />
```

Then reader looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
export default function ReadTextFile({filename}){
  const reader = useRef(new FileReader()).current;
    useEffect(() => {
    if (fileName) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(fileName);
    }
  }, [fileName]);

  useEffect(() => {
    reader.onload = () => {
      console.log(reader.result)
    };
    reader.onerror = () => {
      console.log(reader.error)
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      reader.onload = null;
      reader.onerror = null;
    };
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Why not combine the second two useEffects? `reader.onload = null` seems to be cleanup for `reader.onload = () => {/*stuff*/}`

Answer (score 0):

fixed file upload as below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


class Create extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: 'React'
        };
    }

    showFile = () => {
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
            var preview = document.getElementById('show-text');
            var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader()

            var textFile = /text.*/;

            if (file.type.match(textFile)) {
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    preview.innerHTML = event.target.result;
                }
            } else {
                preview.innerHTML = "<span class='error'>No file!</span>";
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);

        } else {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="file" onChange={this.showFile} />
                <div id="show-text">Choose text File</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Create;
```